# Find all Nash equilibria

Tags: self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

This question is from [the Dutta’s book](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=m1apPLqiIEkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=dutta%20game%20theory&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=dutta%20game%20theory&f=false)

Each of the two roommmates simultaneously volunteer an time between 0 and 3 hours to clean their house. (Their choice doesn’t need to be integer) if roommate 1 volunteers x hours and the roommate 2 volunteers y hours , then the payoff to roommate 1 is $4\sqrt{x+y}-x$ the payoff to roommate 2 is $4\sqrt{x+y}-y$.

I need to find the best response functions and all the Nash equilibria.

—-

My attempt:

First I found the BR for R1

$$max_{\{x\}} \{4\sqrt{x+y}-x\}$$

$$\partial U_1/\partial x = 2(x+y)^{-1/2} -1=0$$
$$BR_1(y)=x(y)=4-y$$

Similarly I found the BR for R2 as follows

$$BR_2(x)=y(x)=4-x$$

So the Nash equilibrium is

$$x=y=2$$

—-

I only find only one Nash equilibrium. Are there any other Nash equilibria ? I am not sure for my solution. I guess there is a tricky point in this question, but I cannot see. Please share your ideas with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation shows that for every $s \in [0,4]$, the pair $(x,y)=(s,4-s)$ is a pure Nash equilibrium, and these are the only pure Nash equlibria.

There are no other mixed Nash equilibria. Given any distribution $\mu$ on $[0,4]$, there is a unique $y=y(\mu)$ that maximizes
$\int 4\sqrt{x+y}-y \, d\mu(x)$, namely the unique solution of
$$0=\psi(y)=\int \bigl(2(x+y)^{-1/2} -1 \bigr)\, d\mu(x) \,.$$
Thus the only best response to $\mu$ is the measure concentrated at $y=y(\mu)$. Finally, the only best response to $y$ is $4-y$.

Comment: Thank you dear Peres